# EXECABORT Transaction discarded because of previous error

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis, jedis

I am trying to use redis cache with spring MVC but the issue I am getting when I try to use @Cacheable  over the controller method. It gives me the above error. I looked at various articles it suggests some command issue. But via Java code we are just annotating it with @Cacheable. can anyone help on this please?
spring data redis 1.4.1.RELEASE
JEDIS 2.6.1

Controller->
@Cacheable("testRedis")
@RequestMapping(value = "/testCache", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = { "application/json",
"application/xml" })
public String test(@RequestParam(value = "message", required = false) String message) throws Exception {
return "from method---"+message;
}

Comment: "I looked at various articles it suggests some command issue." That's exactly what it is. To get further help, please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You're using spring data and Jedis in the same project? You should just need one :) run `redis-cli monitor` to see what's happening while you run the command.